# How to find the index location for list of variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python.  I have a dataframe df_A and I want to find out the location where Col1 in df_A matches any of the variable in list_B and then remove those rows. i.e. remove the row 0, 2, & 4 in the following example.  What are the possible ways to achieve that?  Many thanks.

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'AA'], 'Col2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
list_B = ('AA','CC')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for boolean mask and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `df_A.index`:

```
idx = df_A.index[df_A['Col1'].isin(list_B)]
print (idx)
Int64Index([0, 2, 4], dtype='int64')
```

If need `list`:

```
idx = df_A.index[df_A['Col1'].isin(list_B)].tolist()
print (idx)
[0, 2, 4]
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df_A['Col1'].isin(list_B))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: Col1, dtype: bool
```

For filtering all rows by list:

```
df1 = df_A[df_A['Col1'].isin(list_B)]
print (df1)
  Col1  Col2
0   AA     1
2   CC     3
4   AA     5
```

And for filter out values by list invert booleanmask by `~`:

```
df2 = df_A[~df_A['Col1'].isin(list_B)]
print (df2)
  Col1  Col2
1   BB     2
3   DD     4
```

**Detail**:

```
print (~df_A['Col1'].isin(list_B))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: Col1, dtype: bool
```